# Character Encoding in matlab

Tags: matlab, character

I am using matlab for some image processing purpose. When I tries to read such 
files whose name contains German, French characters, it can not read it.
It throws an error:

```
File does not Exist

imread('22_Raven-Symoné_0010.JPG')
```

How would it solve it?

Comment: You may be out of luck with that.  I've found http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86186-working-with-unicode-paths which seems to indicate MATLAB just plain doesn't like Unicode for file names.

Comment: Try constructing your string like `'22_Raven-Symon' char(<something>) '_0020.JPG'`. You'd need the code for each character though.

Comment: In ML2013a the problem no longer exists. Try `dir()`, probably it outputs the name as required.